# Not getting callback after task reservation fails

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio TaskRouter. A call comes into our number, Twilio makes an API call to our incoming call endpoint. I send the following response:

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">Thank you for calling</Say>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="/Call/HoldMusic" workflowSid="WW..."/>
</Response>
```

The call is successfully enqueued and my workflow kicks off. I get the workflow assignment callback and respond with the following JSON:

```
{
  "instruction": "dequeue",
  "to": "+18885551213",
  "timeout": 10,
  "status_callback_url": "/Workflow/Changed",
  "status_callback_events": "initiated,ringing,answered,completed",
  "from": "+18885551212"
}
```

The outbound call is successfully made to my "to" number. If I accept the call, I get the reservation.accepted event to my task router callback endpoint. If I don't accept the call (let it timeout), I don't get a notification. Because I don't get a notification the dequeue failed, I can't cancel the reservation and have the call ring down through the queue.

I also changed the workflow assignment callback to return a "call" instruction and set the "status_callback_url" but again I only receive a callback if the call is answered, not if the call times out.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or something fundamental I'm not understanding?

Comment: The `status_callback_url` should receive a callback when the call times out. I don't think your code is incorrect, so I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and providing some task SIDs where this didn't work. They should be able to dig into it. One thing I'm wondering, Twilio is supposed to make `GET` requests to that URL, is your application set to receive `GET` requests?

Comment: The callback URL accepts either GET or POST. I don't see anything in the debugger console either. I will get in touch with support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. If you don't include the "status_callback_events" value, then Twilio will send an event for **all** events. The missing event was *no-answer*. I'm marking this as answered so that future people can see the list of Twilio events for the *dequeue* and *call* instruction.

Current known list of *dequeue* and *call* events:

- queued
- no-answer
- initiated
- ringing
- answered
- completed
- in-progress
- busy
- canceled
- failed